# spring5.3 mvc + jpa + hibernate5.6, coexistence of repositories and hibernate DAO (no spring boot)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am migrating an application from plain Hibernate to JPA, so I need to keep the many DAOs we have working, but also having JPA repositories to handle some tables in some use cases.

I run into problem with **transactions**. I call a method of a service that is @Transactional from a simple controller but I get this stacktrace :

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(SessionImpl.java:3492) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1408) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1403) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:113) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:95) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:97) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:916) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:727) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.myActualServiceMethod(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

Here is my JpaConfiguration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {
                "com.myapp.project.metier.domain.dao.repos"
        }
)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "jpaAuditorProvider")
public class JpaConfig {

@Bean
public AuditorAware<String> jpaAuditorProvider() {
    return new UsernameAuditorAware();
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
            = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource);
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.myapp.project.metier.domain.entities");
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("MyPersistenceUnit");
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

    return em;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/my_database");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("rootmdp");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    final JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

final Properties additionalProperties() {

    final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class",
            "org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext");
    // hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
    // hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class",
    //   "jta");
    //       "org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext");
    // hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform",
    //     "org.jadira.usertype.spi.jta.LocalTransactionManagerPlatform");
    return hibernateProperties;
}

// needed by the old DAOs that are not JPA repositories
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean hibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    hibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return hibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    // this causes an exception even though the documentation says it should be used
    // org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    /*return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);*/
}
```

}

The rest of my configuration is XML things (it's an old Spring MVC app)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Remove the `LocalEntityManagerFactory` and configure a `LocalSessionFactory` instead. As of hibernate 5.3 the `SessionFactory` is also an `EntityManagerFactory`. So you only need one.

Comment: I removed the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` bean and added a
`@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
}` now I get `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available` error when JPA repositories try to instantiante.
Though the documentation of `LocalSessionFactory ` says very interesting things, it's not clear how to implement it, I will dig.

Comment: Rename the method to `entityManagerFactory` or put both bean names in the `@Bean` annotation. Also make sure that you are wiring that into the `JpaTransactionManager` (the `SessionFactory`).

Comment: I did that `@Bean(name = {"entityManagerFactory", "sessionFactory"})
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource)` and it worked ! But with the `JpaTransactionManager` (same as original post) the code ran but nothing was written to DB. so I switched to `HibernateTransactionManager` and now it works well with transactions ! Thank you :) Don't know if it's "good" to not use `JpaTransactionManager` though